# Reload a whole tree or a single node

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How can I either reload a whole tree and/or a single node allong with all childs of these node from the scope of the node.

The Single-Node currently this is done by expanding but now there is the need for a reload button for the whole grid and for the selected node. I looked at the nodeinterface there is is nothing useful like a reload. The node are using a automodel at the moment, meaning no explicit model is created.

**revished edit**

I also tried to call removeAll() on a treestore and also removeAll() on the tree. The first calls the reader method for each removed node with the node itself as param which then result in a error cause there server answer all the invalid request with a empty result. The second removes all but also with errors.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question:

You might try call the **[removeAll()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-method-removeAll)** of the tree instead of the store.

Comment: Tank you for the reply, but I already tried this. See may edit. Any other advice?